# how manipulate CSS display property using active class with JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wished to output a small pop up window to confirm if the user want to escape or stay on the page however, as soon as i click on the RUN input id="openBtn" the pop up window appears then disappear right away. I dont know what i did wrong

CSS

```
.pop-up{
    display: none;
}

.pop-up.active{
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #fff;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #222831;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    height: 150px;
    width: 250px;
    top: 200px;
    left: 170px;
    border: 5px double #393E46;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 2px 4px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

SCRIPT.JS

```
const openBtn = document.getElementById("openBtn");
const popUp = document.querySelector('.pop-up');
const stayBtn = document.getElementById("stayBtn");

openBtn.addEventListener('click', () =>{
    popUp.classList.add('active')
})

stayBtn.addEventListener('click', () =>{
    popUp.classList.remove('active')
})
```

HTML

```
<div class="controls">
                <div class="left"></div>
                <form action="" method="post" class="right">
                    <input type="submit" name="fight" value="FIGHT">
                    <input type="submit" name="pkmn" value="PKMN">
                    <input type="submit" name="item" value="ITEM">
                    <input type="submit" id="openBtn" value="RUN">
                
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pop-up">
            <p>Escape battle?</p>
            <form action="" method="post" class="buttons">
                <input type="submit" class="button" id="stayBtn" name="stay" value="Stay">
                <input type="submit" class="button" name="escape" id="run" value="Run">
            </form>
    </div>
```

I just wanted to have an confirm to exit option where i use a class to have the css display switch to none and flex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing  `e.preventDefault()` on your `openBtn`,

Inside the modal I used `button type="button"` instead of `input="submit"` which is better practice and with that you don't need `e.preventDefault()`

**Note:** I didn't change your `input` controls to `button` as I don't know what are you doing with it.

```js
const openBtn = document.getElementById("openBtn");
const popUp = document.querySelector('.pop-up');
const stayBtn = document.getElementById("stayBtn");

openBtn.addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.preventDefault()
  popUp.classList.add('active')
})

stayBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  popUp.classList.remove('active')
})
```

```css
.pop-up {
  display: none;
}

.pop-up.active {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #222831;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  height: 150px;
  width: 250px;
  top: 200px;
  left: 170px;
  border: 5px double #393E46;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 2px 4px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<div class="controls">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <form action="" method="post" class="right">
    <input type="submit" name="fight" value="FIGHT">
    <input type="submit" name="pkmn" value="PKMN">
    <input type="submit" name="item" value="ITEM">
    <input type="submit" id="openBtn" value="RUN">
  </form>
</div>
<div class="pop-up">
  <p>Escape battle?</p>
  <button type="button" class="button" id="stayBtn" name="stay">Stay</button>
  <button type="button" class="button" name="escape" id="run" value="Run">Run</button>
</div>
```

Comment: You changed your answer after I had made the comment. Apologies.

Comment: but now that I used the code above I cant use $_POST to destroy and unset my session and redierect to poage index.php

Comment: i mean hence why i was using input tags insted of buttons. but your code works best though

Comment: @dorkcoding then use your code and add `e.preventDefault()` in `stayBtn` listener  as I did for `openBtn`

Answer (score 0):

You are on a form .Whenever you click a button or `input[submit]`,You  will give a post request with the given values to the server .After sending the request ,the browser will show you its response by default .To not have the redirect, you have to add `e.preventDefault()`.For this scenario, You will have to change to

```
openBtn.addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.preventDefault()
  popUp.classList.add('active')
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation! now i understand better how it should work. :D